# migrating old paperclip images from filesystem to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am uploading new paperclip attachments to AWS S3. But i have a lot of old images on the file system that needs be migrated to S3. I am trying this rake task but i am not able to figure out how i should provide the path to bucket on S3.

```
task :copy_paperclip_data => :environment do
  @toycars = ToyCar.find :all
  @toycars.each do |toycar|
    unless toycar.image_file_name.blank?
      filename = Rails.root.join('public', 'system', 'images', toycar.id.to_s, 'original', toycar.image_file_name) # this allows me to change path on filesystem, but i want to make it upload on s3

      if File.exists? filename
        image = File.new filename
        toycar.image = image
        toycar.save

        image.close
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you looked at the aws s3 gem: http://amazon.rubyforge.org ?

Comment: @ArvindMehra Hi man, can you tell me why you moved to S3, isn't a good idea to use the file system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it... I changed my rake task into this, I am saving my every ToyCar object image  again and it does the job....

```
namespace :migrate_to_s3 do

  desc "Upload images to S3"
  task :toy_cars => :environment do
    toy_cars = ToyCar.all
    toy_cars.each do |car|
      image = Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/system/#{car.logo.path}"].first
      if image.present?
        car.update(:logo => File.open(image))
        puts "uploading"
      end
    end
  end

end
```